# Vertical direction of string into mysql

Tags: php

I want to change the direction of letters of string which is saves into db.
e.g I want the word HELLO to appear like this:

```
    H W
    E O
    L R
    L L
    O D
```

I try this but show me question marks ?:

```
echo "<table>";

$res=$functions->query("SELECT string1 FROM table");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
    $hor=str_split($row['string1']);
    foreach ($hor as $letter) {
         $vert=$letter."\n";        
    }
    echo"<th>".$vert."</th>";   
}

// other functions... 

echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your foreach statement with the code below:

```
foreach($hor as $letter) {
    $vert .= $letter . "\n";
}
```

Your forgot about [concatenating](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) issue which is necessary to display all letters.

Answer (score 0):

You need to append to $vert other wise you keep overwriting and only get the last value

```
foreach ($hor as $letter) {
  $vert=$vert.$letter."\n";        
}
```

[DEMO](http://rextester.com/FXQH41288)

Comment: Your answer is correct but only in latin characters. I want to display greek characters but the output is ? into rhombus

Comment: Then you should say that in your question instead of using `HELLO`

Answer (score 0):

Tada! Try this, the explanations are in comments in the code:

```
$str = "HELLO HOW YA DOING WORLD?";

// Convert $str to an array of rows of letters.
$strWords          = explode(' ', $str);
$strLettersRowsArr = array_map('mb_split', $strWords);

// Get maximium number of rows of letters e.g. `strlen("WORLD?")` => `6`.
$maxRows = 0;
foreach ($strLettersRowsArr as $lettersArr) {
    if (count($lettersArr) > $maxRows) {
        $maxRows = count($lettersArr);
    }
}

// Pad out the elements of $strLettersRowsArr with spaces that aren't as long as the longest word.
// e.g.
// from:
// [
//     ['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'],
//     ['d', 'u', 'd', 'e'],
// ]
// to:
// [
//     ['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'],
//     ['d', 'u', 'd', 'e', ' '],
// ]
foreach ($strLettersRowsArr as $key => &$lettersArr) {
    while (count($lettersArr) < $maxRows) {
        $lettersArr[] = ' ';
    }
}
unset($lettersArr);

// Get the columns of letters.
// e.g.
// from:
// [
//     ['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'],
//     ['w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd'],
// ]
// to:
// [
//     ['H', 'w'],
//     ['e', 'o'],
//     ['l', 'r'],
//     ['l', 'l'],
//     ['o', 'd'],
// ]
$strLettersColumnsArr = [];
for ($row = 0; $row < $maxRows; $row++) {
    $strLettersColumnsArr[] = array_column($strLettersRowsArr, $row);
}

// Print out letter columns.
foreach ($strLettersColumnsArr as $lettersColumnArr) {
    foreach ($lettersColumnArr as $letter) {
        echo "$letter ";
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

This outputs:

```
H H Y D W 
E O A O O 
L W   I R 
L     N L 
O     G D 
        ?
```

Comment: I have problem with greek letter. It is appeared questionmarks ??

Comment: @teo Firstly you should have included that requirement in your question to begin with. Secondly, the solution is to use [`mb_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-split.php)