# Vertical letter of a string

Tags: php, regex

I want to change the direction of letters of string which eg I want the word HELLO WORLD to appear like this:

```
H  W
E  O
L  R
L  L
O  D
```

I do this but do not work!

```
 $word=preg_split('/s',string);
    $hor_letter=preg_split('//u,'$word);
        foreach ($hor_letter as $letter) {
             $vert_letter=$letter."\n";        
        }
```

The result is:

```
H
E
L
L
O 

W
O
R
L
D
```

Comment: What happens if there is only 10 characters? And 12? For example: `THIS WORLD` and `THESE WORLDS`

Comment: Great question! That's a tricky one, I assume you want this to still work for longer/shorter words and for more than just 2 words though, right?

Comment: I try it for a string for less 3 words and almost for 10 words

Comment: Is `/s` a typo in here or in your code? I guess that should be `\s`

Comment: you have wrote *I want the word HELLO WORLD to appear like this:*. If the solution should cover a more extended inputs - you should extend your question

Comment: you posted this already https://stackoverflow.com/q/46621042/1415724 and received an answer and accepted it.

Comment: it's bad to post duplicates. Why are doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Tada! Try this, the explanations are in comments in the code:

```
$str = "HELLO HOW YA DOING WORLD?";

// Convert $str to an array of rows of letters.
$strWords          = explode(' ', $str);
$strLettersRowsArr = array_map('str_split', $strWords);

// Get maximium number of rows of letters e.g. `strlen("WORLD?")` => `6`.
$maxRows = 0;
foreach ($strLettersRowsArr as $lettersArr) {
    if (count($lettersArr) > $maxRows) {
        $maxRows = count($lettersArr);
    }
}

// Pad out the elements of $strLettersRowsArr with spaces that aren't as long as the longest word.
// e.g.
// from:
// [
//     ['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'],
//     ['d', 'u', 'd', 'e'],
// ]
// to:
// [
//     ['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'],
//     ['d', 'u', 'd', 'e', ' '],
// ]
foreach ($strLettersRowsArr as $key => &$lettersArr) {
    while (count($lettersArr) < $maxRows) {
        $lettersArr[] = ' ';
    }
}
unset($lettersArr);

// Get the columns of letters.
// e.g.
// from:
// [
//     ['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'],
//     ['w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd'],
// ]
// to:
// [
//     ['H', 'w'],
//     ['e', 'o'],
//     ['l', 'r'],
//     ['l', 'l'],
//     ['o', 'd'],
// ]
$strLettersColumnsArr = [];
for ($row = 0; $row < $maxRows; $row++) {
    $strLettersColumnsArr[] = array_column($strLettersRowsArr, $row);
}

// Print out letter columns.
foreach ($strLettersColumnsArr as $lettersColumnArr) {
    foreach ($lettersColumnArr as $letter) {
        echo "$letter ";
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

This outputs:

```
H H Y D W 
E O A O O 
L W   I R 
L     N L 
O     G D 
        ?
```

Comment: I don't understand why you would ever need an output like this, but regardless, good job.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Heh, I coded it on the fly just now, I just wanted the challenge :P